# Legend about the Invention of Steel

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to track down a legend concerning the invention of steel (originally told to me by a group of touring historians visiting my Australian high school 40 years ago).

Under the legend, a blacksmith was working with iron and was being assisted by a not-so-competent slave.  The blacksmith became angry with the slave and picked up a hot iron implement and plunged it into the slave, killing him.  The slave's body added the needed carbon to the iron, producing steel.

I would appreciate any reference to this legend.  What city did it supposedly occur in?

Comment: Plunging the white hot iron into the unfortunate slave's body would have had the effect of cooling it abruptly which would have effects on its properties . But the story in itself sounds unverifiable .

Comment: @schweppz I don’t think OP is looking for verification of the legend, just to know where it comes from.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please read the [tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for identification requests and [edit your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/25795/edit) to include the sort of additional details that could help narrow down the possibilities. As @bobble says in their [comment](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25795/legend-about-the-invention-of-steel#comment39242_25795), knowing more specifically when and where you heard this story would be helpful.

Comment: bobble, Australia, 40 years ago.
schweppz, you are correct.

Comment: There are many stories about tempering Damascus steel swords by stabbing them into slaves, but that is a very specific type of steel. This legend was about steel in general?

Comment: Clara Diaz Sanchez, if there are many such stories, then I would just be after any reference / link to any of them.  Perhaps somewhere in the retelling to me, the story changed from Damascus steel in particular to the invention of steel in general.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the earliest reference to quenching a sword in a body is [an 1894 *Chicago Tribune* article](https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/iss/kap_8/advanced/t8_4_1.html):

[image: Image of the Chicago Tribune article]

> Then let the master workman, having cold-hammered the blade to a smooth and thin edge, thrust it into the fire of the cedarwood charcoal, in and out, while reciting the prayer to the God Balhal until the steel be of the color of the red of the rising sun when he comes up over the desert towards the East, and then with a quick motion pass the same from the heel thereof to the point, six times through the most fleshy portion of the slave's' back an thighs, when it shall have become the purple of the king. Then, if with one swing and one stroke of the right arm of the master workman it severs the head of the slave from his body, and display not nick nor crack along its edge, and the blade may be bent around the body of a man and break not, it shall be accepted as perfect weapon, sacred to the service of the God Balhal, and the owner thereof may thrust it into a scabbard of asses' skin, brazen with brass, and hung to a girdle of camel's wool dyed in royal purple.

Professor Helmut Föll goes on to explain that this was likely a joke article.

> Aha! A discovery made by Prof von Eulenspiegel! That sounds rather good - except if you know, like every German, that "Eulenspiegel" is never the name of a person but a synonym for a trickster, somebody who plays you for a sucker.
> Moreover, a copper cylinder was found that contained the ancient smiths' secret in writing! That must be the only copper cylinder used for keeping writings that was ever found in antiquity. Moreover once more, it contains writings from the the only ancient smith known to humankind who was capable of writing. Yes, indeed!
>
> So some evil German at the end of the 19th century invented the story and spread it, disguised as archaeological discovery? Not so. Every German reading the Berliner Tageblatt around 1894 would have immediately realized that the article was a joke or a satirical comment to the craze about "damascene steel" that exercised scientists and "damascene steel" aficionados mightily in these times.
>
> I would not be surprised eiher (sic) if it turns out that the article was originally published on April 1st.

Comment: And yes, this does not answer the question of the invention of steel via this method, but it seemed to fit the spirit.